# auto_refresh div dosen't work with me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so im a beginner in php & javascript who wants to make a div contains an ads script in it to refresh every minute .
i thought i wrote everything right in my code :

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').load('reload.html').fadeIn("slow");
}, 60000); // refresh every 60000 milliseconds


</script>

<div id="load"></div>
```

and this is the reload file :

```
<html>
<script src="http://www.[random-website].com/getad.php?46151;80391;300x250"></script>
</html>
```

when the div reloads nothing happens , what the probleme ?

Comment: holy crap jquery 1.3? bro ... please in the name of all that is good update that.

Comment: Check your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080403/jquery-auto-refresh-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because a div with that id doesnt exist in that moment. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
   $('#load').load('reload.html').fadeIn("slow");
   }, 60000); // refresh every 60000 milliseconds
});

</script>
```

You can also move your `script` block after `<div id="load"></div>`

You might try to update your jquery version. Ver 1.3 is obsolete.